# ChangeDisplaySettingsEx fails with BAD_MODE for fake display

Tags: c++, winapi, operating-system

I'm creating a fake display using the command DisplaySwitch.exe /extend and then, I try to change the resolution for this display using the following code.

```
DISPLAY_DEVICE display;
display.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, 1, &display, EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME);
DEVMODE dvMode;
ZeroMemory(&dvMode, sizeof(DEVMODE));
dvMode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
dvMode.dmPelsHeight = 1080;
dvMode.dmPelsWidth = 1920;
dvMode.dmBitsPerPel = 32;
dvMode.dmFields = (DM_BITSPERPEL|DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT);
long value = ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(display.DeviceName, &dvMode, NULL, CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY | CDS_RESET, NULL);
```

This code works for my notebook display, but it always return DISP_CHANGE_BADMODE for the extended one. The returned DISPLAY_DEVICE seems valid because EnumDisplaySettings returns the correct current resolution.
If I use the Adjust Screen Resolution from windows, everything works as expected.